# Using a cookie to establish if a web page is still opened

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cookies

I want to establish if a determinated page of my web site is currently opened, from others web page. All on client's side (thus all by Js Code).
I tried to write the following code, but it doesn't behave as expected.

```
function setCookie (name, value, seconds)
{
     if (typeof(seconds) != 'undefined') {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        var expires = "";
    }
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires;
}
function web_page_alive()
{
    setCookie("page_alive","true", 3);
}

page_alive_schedule=self.setInterval("web_page_alive()",1000);
```

So, every second, the "page_alive" cookie is set to true with an expires time of 3 seconds.
Thus, as long as the web page will remain opened, the cookie will be set to true.
When the user closes the web page, in 3 seconds the cookie should be destroyed by the browser. Strangely the cookie remains set ( with a "back" expires time ) also when i close the page. I'm using FF 11. Does anyone know how is this possibile? Thank you all.

Comment: So, you are going to run that function every 1 second to set the cookie for every 3 Second. Kinda sounds ackward

Comment: What is actually that you are trying to check if another page is open?

Comment: Is it server side where you want to know if the web-page is still open? Or is it another window/tab?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that the values are so important, it was just to understand how the browser will behave. Unfortunatly, i can't understand why it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't set an expiry, the cookie will be expired when you close the page. Session cookies work like that

Comment: @Starx : From another web page, within its Js code, I want to check if the page with the code that I posted earlier is still opened and react in different ways.

Comment: This is trivial (no cookies, timeouts, or polling required) with shared [web workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/).  What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: @Nemoy : If I don't set an expiry, the cookie will remain as long as the current browser session will remain opened. So if the user closes only that window/tab and  he continues using others windows/tabs, the cookie will remain.

Comment: @ephemient: Mostly IE 8/9 and FF 10. I'd prefer a solution that grantes compatibility. I'm sure that it can be done, just with cookies, but I don't understand why the browser behaves in that way. I'll go crazy.

Comment: @pane619: K got it, you need it for single tab only

Comment: Are you using different cookie names for different pages?

Comment: I use only one cookie, for this purpose. The page that is "important" writes the cookie to tell that is "alive". Others pages (opened in different tabs/windows) check  this cookie, but only reading it, not writing.

Comment: Try setting the cookie `onload` and removing it `onunload` of body, instead of using setInterval

Comment: That sounds just like a good hint! I'll tray in a few minutes =)

Comment: @pane619 Instead of setting "true", set the current time (milliseconds). In the other tabs, check the value: if it's too old, it means the main tab has died.

Comment: Ok, I just fixed the problem handling all the stuff with the two events onload and onunload. Thank you very much Nemoy! @Manish: That could be an alternative solution, thanks!

Comment: @pane619 I don't think you'll get the unload event if the browser crashes. Checking the timestamp would be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This is working correctly for me.

Open both `setter.html` and `checker.html` (below) in your browser.

Every fifteen seconds `checker.html` will check the value of the cookie and alert it.

As long as `setter.html` is open and setting its cookie, `checker.html` will display **true**.

But once you close `setter.html`, then `checker.html` will display **undefined**.

Here is setter.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie (name, value, seconds)
{
     if (typeof(seconds) != 'undefined') {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        var expires = "";
    }
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires;
}
function web_page_alive()
{
    setCookie("page_alive","true", 3);
}

page_alive_schedule=self.setInterval("web_page_alive()",1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the setter.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is checker.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function web_page_alive()
{
    var value = getCookie("page_alive");
    alert(value);
}

page_alive_schedule=self.setInterval("web_page_alive()",15000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the checker.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, using getCookie from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)